# Copying Cookies and Sessions

Tags: php, http, session, cookies

I am building a website that pulls information from a few of other websites. The data pulled includes text, numbers and links.
I am having success pulling the text and number in, however the links are causing a problem.

I can copy the links to the site, however when they are clicked on another computer that doesn't have the cookies installed then it just brings me to a generic search page, and not the page that has the results on that I am searching. Is it possible to 'send' the cookies to the new computer when the link is clicked, so the session can carry on?

I am a new to this!

Comment: I think you will need AJAX for this sir.